# Room Android: Unable to grant a connection to thread (Connection Pool for database)

Tags: android, sqlite, android-room

I have the following code using Room library to handle sqldatabase. I waSthe downloadCustomers method many times but all of a sudden i got the following message inside at the mDatabase.repoCustomer().deleteCustomers() :

**Message:**

*The connection pool for database has been unable to grant a connection to thread room android*

This happened only once and i wiped the emulator so i can run it again. 
I read in forums that "*a transaction might be open by a thread*", but Room library handles automatically situations like these.

Any ideas?

**Emulator:** Emulator API 27 with Google Play (not Google APIs)

**Something to consider:** Sometimes when i run apps with Google play strange things happen e.x runs an app with 2 instances at the same time. But i dont want to make quick assumptions.

Thank you.

```
public abstract class AppDatabase extends RoomDatabase {

private static AppDatabase sInstance;

@VisibleForTesting
public static final String DATABASE_NAME = "Database_db";

public abstract CustomerDao repoCustomer();


public static AppDatabase getInstance(Context context) {

    if (sInstance == null) {
        synchronized (AppDatabase.class) {
            if (sInstance == null) {
                sInstance = Room.databaseBuilder(context.getApplicationContext(), AppDatabase.class, DATABASE_NAME).build();

            }
        }
    }
    return sInstance;
}


public void downloadCustomers(final String table){

        executors.diskIO().execute(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                mDatabase.repoCustomer().deleteCustomers();

                if (mDatabase.repoCustomer().getAllCustomers().size() == 0) {
                    makeHttpRequest();
                 }
             });
        }  
}


@Dao
public interface CustomerDao {

    @Transaction @Query("SELECT * FROM Customer")
    LiveData<List<Customer>> getAllCustomersLive();

    @Transaction @Query("SELECT * FROM Customer")
    List<Customer> getAllCustomers();

    @Transaction @Insert(onConflict = OnConflictStrategy.REPLACE)
    void insertCustomers(List<Customer> Customers);

    @Query("DELETE FROM Customer")
    int deleteCustomers();
}
```